# Systemd won't start service anymore

Tags: systemd

I searching now already for more then 2 hours..

A time ago i made an systemd service for an PHP app. This worked great untill yesterday morning. The service stopped working on boot and the command 'sudo systemctl start TcpSocket' doesn't work either, it shows the blinking cursor and i have to exit it with ctrl+c.

Running the app with the command 'php /home/ttn-admin/Scripts/TcpSocket.php' works without problems.

Content of the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=TcpSocket Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /home/ttn-admin/Scripts/TcpSocket.php

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the command 'journalctl -u TcpSocket.service -f -n100' shows only untill yesterday morning.

I don't know where to look anymore and why it stopped working after some years...

Thanks.

Edit 1:

Output of 'systemctl status TcpSocket':

```
TcpSocket.service - TcpSocket Service Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/TcpSocket.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled) Active: inactive (dead)
```

Output of 'systemctl status':

```
ttn-server
    State: starting
     Jobs: 16 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Tue 2023-01-10 13:07:37 UTC; 51s ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─user.slice 
           │ └─user-0.slice 
           │   ├─session-1.scope 
           │   │ ├─ 1317 /usr/libexec/cockpit-session localhost
           │   │ ├─ 1331 cockpit-bridge
           │   │ ├─ 1352 /usr/libexec/cockpit-pcp
           │   │ ├─ 1374 /bin/bash
           │   │ ├─ 1402 systemctl status
           │   │ └─ 1403 less
           │   └─user@0.service …
           │     ├─session.slice 
           │     │ └─dbus-broker.service 
           │     │   ├─ 1366 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope user
           │     │   └─ 1370 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id b5d31d5285d04f3abc6786e2fd9dd45e --max-bytes 100000000000000 --max>
           │     └─init.scope 
           │       ├─ 1322 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
           │       └─ 1323 (sd-pam)
           ├─init.scope 
           │ └─ 1 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd rhgb --switched-root --system --deserialize 31
           └─system.slice 
             ├─irqbalance.service 
             │ └─ 766 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
             ├─abrt-journal-core.service 
             │ └─ 791 /usr/bin/abrt-dump-journal-core -D -T -f -e
             ├─packagekit.service 
             │ └─ 1369 /usr/libexec/packagekitd
             ├─systemd-udevd.service 
             │ └─ 623 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
             ├─dbus-broker.service 
             │ ├─ 760 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope system --audit
             │ └─ 762 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id b5d31d5285d04f3abc6786e2fd9dd45e --max-bytes 536870912 --max-fds 4096 --m>
             ├─systemd-homed.service 
             │ └─ 771 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-homed
             ├─mariadb.service 
             │ └─ 901 /usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr
             ├─polkit.service 
             │ └─ 768 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
             ├─realmd.service 
             │ └─ 1357 /usr/libexec/realmd
             ├─systemd-timedated.service 
             │ └─ 1358 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-timedated
             ├─chronyd.service 
             │ └─ 776 /usr/sbin/chronyd -F 2
             ├─auditd.service 
             │ ├─ 727 /sbin/auditd
             │ └─ 729 /usr/sbin/sedispatch
             ├─php-fpm.service 
             │ ├─ 813 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
             │ ├─ 831 php-fpm: pool www
             │ ├─ 832 php-fpm: pool www
             │ ├─ 833 php-fpm: pool www
             │ ├─ 834 php-fpm: pool www
             │ └─ 835 php-fpm: pool www
             ├─abrt-xorg.service 
             │ └─ 793 /usr/bin/abrt-dump-journal-xorg -fxtD
             ├─ModemManager.service 
             │ └─ 796 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
             ├─systemd-journald.service 
             │ └─ 611 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
             ├─atd.service 
             │ └─ 1020 /usr/sbin/atd -f
             ├─sshd.service 
             │ └─ 819 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
             ├─crond.service 
             │ └─ 1031 /usr/sbin/crond -n
             ├─NetworkManager.service 
             │ └─ 804 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
             ├─cockpit.service 
             │ └─ 1303 /usr/libexec/cockpit-tls
             ├─systemd-hostnamed.service 
             │ └─ 1342 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-hostnamed
             ├─gssproxy.service 
             │ └─ 821 /usr/sbin/gssproxy -D
             ├─rsyslog.service 
             │ └─ 769 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
             ├─abrtd.service 
             │ └─ 773 /usr/sbin/abrtd -d -s
             ├─firewalld.service 
             │ └─ 797 /usr/bin/python3 -s /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
             ├─systemd-userdbd.service 
             │ ├─ 726 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-userdbd
             │ ├─ 733 systemd-userwork
             │ ├─ 734 systemd-userwork
             │ └─ 735 systemd-userwork
             ├─system-cockpithttps.slice 
             │ └─cockpit-wsinstance-https@e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.service 
             │   ├─ 1309 /usr/libexec/cockpit-ws --for-tls-proxy --port=0
             │   └─ 1319 /usr/bin/ssh-agent
             ├─httpd.service 
             │ ├─ 1000 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ ├─ 1089 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ ├─ 1090 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ ├─ 1091 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ └─ 1094 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─systemd-oomd.service 
             │ └─ 724 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-oomd
             ├─mcelog.service 
             │ └─ 767 /usr/sbin/mcelog --daemon --foreground
             ├─systemd-resolved.service 
             │ └─ 725 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
             ├─pmcd.service 
             │ ├─ 1004 /usr/bin/sh /usr/libexec/pcp/lib/pmcd start-systemd
             │ └─ 1297 /usr/libexec/pcp/bin/pmcd_wait
             ├─system-getty.slice 
             │ └─getty@tty1.service 
             │   └─ 1059 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
             ├─smartd.service 
             │ └─ 770 /usr/sbin/smartd -n -q never --capabilities=mail
             ├─systemd-logind.service 
             │ └─ 772 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
             └─abrt-oops.service 
               └─ 792 /usr/bin/abrt-dump-journal-oops -fxtD
```

Comment: If you run `systemctl status` to get the overall status of the system, does the second line say `State: running` or something different? If it says `State: degraded`, it means one or more services have failed (run `systemctl` without any parameters to see which one(s)). Since your service type is `idle`, your service may start only after every other service has successfully started... and if there is a problem with another service, might not start at all. It sort of seems like the system is waiting for something to complete, but it doesn't.

Comment: systemctl status gives this reponse: ○ TcpSocket.service - TcpSocket Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/TcpSocket.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: I also changed the type to 'simple', this doesn't work either..

Comment: Can the system resolve hostnames, especially its own name? If there is a problem with hostname resolution, it would cause a lot of services to work sluggishly. Also you did not answer my question: was the overall system state `running` or `degraded`, and if `degraded`, which services have failed?

Comment: Add that information to the question so that it doesn't get lost in the comments. If it is showing as disabled, then that is one reason that it doesn't start at boot. Also, run the command manually without the service and look at the output. You can also append the output to a file and then examine it later to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i'm new on this site and also an newbie on linux, i tought the question was for the service status, i didn't even know there was an overall status. I going to collect more info now.

Comment: First post modified, it looks like it's still starting, i looked at the output, but i can't see whats wrong. :(

Comment: with the command systemctl i found out that the service 'pmcd' is in the state 'activating', looks like this is an service of the cockpit interface. I'm going to search for that one

Answer (score 0):

This case is solved, another service was in the activating state.
This was the reason my own service didn't start.

I masked the services 'pmcd' and 'pmlogger' wit systemctl mask command

Thanks to all helpers :D